# New graphics card causes Windows 7 partition to "Blue Screen" on boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, graphics-card, bsod, gpu

Problem:

The other day I walked into my home office only to find my computer trying to boot and repeatedly kicking itself off and then trying to reboot again. After taking out nonessential components and adding them back in one at a time, I discovered that it was the graphics card that was causing issues. I purchased a new graphics card and replaced the old one. Now when I try to boot I enter this loop where it loads the BIOS, then the initial Windows loading screen, followed by a momentary BSOD, then it tries to reboot itself.

I have a dual boot system setup with Ubuntu. Currently I'm using the Ubuntu 14.04 partition which seems to work fine and recognizes the new gpu.

Attempted Troubleshooting:

- Verified that PC has all System Requirements for new GPU.
- After trying to reboot several times it eventually gave me the screen that has the "Start Windows Normally" option or the "Startup Repair (Recommended)" option. I thought it was strange it didn't have the "Safe Mode" option. Both the Startup Repair scan and System Restore were unsuccessful and produced random errors with no cause.
- After several iterations of the previous troubleshooting, I decided to reinstall the entire Windows 7 OS with the installation CD. When I get to the BIOS Boot Menu (after pushing F12) I discovered that the boot sequence lists everything as SATA0, SATA1,etc. as opposed to CD-ROM Drive, Hard Drive, etc. In addition, it is no longer recognizing the CD-ROM Drive. In fact, I believe it is only recognizing the Hard Drive which it calls SATA0. So a reload of the OS is temporarily out of the question. SIDE NOTE: When originally testing to see what components were bad, I reconnected all PSU cables in the proper location and made sure they were seated properly.

System Information:

- Computer: Dell Optiplex 755 (Pre-built)
- OS: Windows 7/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Dual-boot partitions
- Motherboard: Dell DT DR845
- CPU: Intel Core2Duo
- RAM: 4GB DDR2
  Old GPU: PNY GeForce 8500GT DDR2 512MB PCIe
  New GPU: PNY GeForce 610 DDR3 2048MB PCIe

Other forums stated that upgrading from a DDR2 GPU to a DDR3 GPU should not matter and that it only matters for the RAM. Is that true or not? Also, I did not have a chance to uninstall the old GPU's drivers since the card just went bad. Hopefully this is not issue. If it is, can I uninstall them from the BIOS?

I have looked at the other related questions but have yet to find someone with this exact issue. Some body please help figure out the issue before I toss this thing out the window. Thanks.

Comment: You would need to debug the bsod dump file to find the cause.

Comment: Repeatedly mashing F8 on start up should get you safe mode.  Choosing safe mode with networking.  Download DDU and uninstall all video card drivers and re-install new drivers afterwards.

Comment: @Moab Can I do that while in the BIOS?

Comment: When windows has a blue screen it creates a dump file on the hard drive, you would need to install windows debugging tools and load the dump file for analysis.

Comment: I mashed f8 on startup and got to the "Safe Mode" screen. But any option I choose that tries to boot windows results in a BSOD about 5 seconds after the initial Windows loading screen. How am I supposed to debug the issue if I can't get into Windows?